# how to create dummy kafka producer and consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm working on small assignment, where I need to read json messages like we read from kakfa. But as of now I've not kafka installed in my machine.

I've list of json strings in a file and I want to read that file and send single json string as message to producer and consume using consumer until all json strings are sent by producer.

Is there any way I could create any dummy producer and consumer like kafka in my work ? Because once am done I need to share that code with other person to run it in their machine.

Can anyone share any ideas or reference to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a real client, not a dummy one. Kafka needs installed somewhere for any client to work, however.

You therefore need to write code in any language that offers a Kafka library to do this. You seem to previously used Spark, so  use that to read JSON and write to Kafka, for example.

Otherwise, you need to download Kafka, rather than "install", to get CLI tools for producers and consumers.

Or, you can install `kcat` for the same. Ex. Producing a file of json-lines

```
kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -t data-topic < data.jsonl
```

Comment: agree, you will need a real client, as it seems to be your assignment to write the necessary code/config for that.

you can run a kafka broker locally using docker, if you are on the jvm have a look at https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/
alternatively there are some docker images available to start a broker locally